# Поиск тега по тексту

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Скажите пожалуйста, как найти тег по содержащемуся в нем тексту.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<h2><span class="team-disc ars-light"></span>Arsenal</h2>', 'lxml')
a = soup.find('h2') `

# возвращает <h2><span class="team-disc ars-light"></span>Arsenal</h2>

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<h2><span class="team-disc ars-light"></span>Arsenal</h2>', 'lxml')
a = soup.find('h2', text = 'Arsenal')

# Возвращает None
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы найти тег, с заданным текстом:

```
>>> soup.find(text='Arsenal').parent
<h2><span class="team-disc ars-light"></span>Arsenal</h2>
```

Если точное совпадение не нужно, то можно `text=re.compile('Arsenal')` критерий использовать.

Чтобы ограничить найденные теги только `h2` элементами и заданной подстрокой:

```
>>> soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'h2' and 'Arsenal' in tag.text)
<h2><span class="team-disc ars-light"></span>Arsenal</h2>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что нужно найти тег <h2> с заданным текстом, а этот текст содержится не только в теге <h2>

Comment: А как вот это использовать text=re.compile('Arsenal') я не могу понять. html='<h2><span class="team-disc ars-light"></span>Привет, как дела? </h2>' Как сделать чтобы мне вернулся этот тег, даже если в запросе будет такой текст "Привет Алексей, как дела? Ты дома?" Как бы частичное совпадение. Если написать Привет, то да вернётся тег.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<h2><span class="team-disc ars-light"></span>Arsenal</h2>', 'lxml')
print(soup.find('h2').text == 'Arsenal')
```

Comment: Возвращает True

Comment: вы же это хотели